# IOS Array break up error

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I call my server and receive a response with a long string that I break apart and store into arrays. I did this perfectly on Android but can't seem to figure it out in xcode. This is what I have to do for IOS:

Android:

```
while (flag) {
                    ProductListArray.add(ProductListOneString.substring(0, ProductListOneString.indexOf('_')));
                    ProductListOneString = ProductListOneString.substring(ProductListOneString.indexOf('_'));

                    if (ProductListOneString.equals("_")) {
                        flag = false;
                    } else {
                        ProductListOneString = ProductListOneString.substring(1);
                    }
                }


                int index = 2;
                int ArraySize = ProductListArray.size();
                ProductKeycodes = new ArrayList<>();
                while(ArraySize > 0){
                    ProductKeycodes.add(ProductListArray.get(index));
                    index = index + 3;
                    ArraySize = ArraySize - 3;
                }
```

what i have so far in Xcode:

```
NSString *ProductListOneString = response;
    NSMutableArray *ProductListArray;


    bool flag = true;

    while (flag) {

        //[ProductListArray addObject: [ProductListOneString substringFromIndex:0 ProductListOneString: index(@"_", 0)]];


        [ProductListArray addObject: [[ProductListOneString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"] objectAtIndex:0]];
        ProductListOneString = [[ProductListOneString componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"] objectAtIndex:0];

        if ([ProductListOneString isEqualToString: @"_"]) {
            flag = false;
        } else {
            ProductListOneString = [ProductListOneString substringFromIndex: 1];//I get a *signal sigabrt* error here
        }
    }



    NSInteger index = 2;
    int ArraySize = [ProductListArray count];

    NSMutableArray *ProductKeycodes;

    while(ArraySize > 0){

        [ProductKeycodes addObject: [ProductListArray objectAtIndex: index]];

        index = index + 3;
        ArraySize = ArraySize - 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first break up the string into an array of substrings by breaking at "_" and then test to see if the first such substring is an "_" - which it cannot be as the delimiters are not part of the substrings.

Your Android code is iterating to achieve what `componentsSeparatedByString:` does for you in one call. You can replace the `while` completely and add the result of `componentsSeparatedByString:` to your `ProductListArray`.

BTW start variables with a lowercase letter in Objective-C - notice how the syntax coloring is wrong as you used an uppercase letter.

HTH